# Entity Framework eager loading objects related to related object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to load eager Pictures object from User object when i,m trying to query request.

Model

User [Table]

--Pictures [navigational property]

--Friends [navigational property]

Request [Table]

--User [navigational property]

i,m using following query.

```
var req = Context.Requests.Include(e => e.User).Include(d => d.User.Pictures).Where(c => c.Destination.Contains(CityName));
```

if i see the SQL server trace the query which executes has made join to pictures table and got the related data.

but in C# is not able to get eager load pictures objects.

when i try to seek any property of pictures object then [lazy loading occurs] and i can see another query in sql server trace.

how can i access pictures property without lazy loading.?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by turning the Lazy Loading option off in your edmx file, and using the Include("yourtable") method in your queries.

Comment: can you give me an example...i,m using include in my query..directly related objects[like user] gets loaded but user pictures are not loaded..

Comment: what is the data type of the column in wich you store your pictures?